# Car leaks only when started

Tags: car, hyundai, leak

I have stated my car after 2-3 weeks and I noticed some liquid is leaking. This leak happens only when I start the car. It smells like kerosene and the traces are at the front side of the car. Leaking is more actually, like pumping the liquid out of the car. Dark smoke comes out of the exhaust. Engin won't be up for long and stops in few seconds.

What is that liquid?

Edit: found this. Any idea what this pipe transmit?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that you have seen the liquid coming out of that pipe?  Which fuel does your car use?

Comment: Is this car a diesel? Diesel fuel is closely related to kerosene.

Comment: Looks like a  mouse started to chew on your wire harness.

Comment: Petrol car, this part looks wet when I inspected it after some time.

Comment: Not sure what flows in these pipes.

Comment: What you are showing in the photo is not a pipe or tube, but a bundle of wires in a wire loom.  I can only guess that somewhere else a leak is "injecting" oil into the wiring harness and it's leaking out here.

Comment: That or thew wires inside are getting hot enough to melt the electrical tape and make smoke and drip melted plastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the high-pressure fuel supply hose to the fuel rail. You can see the fastening studs on the left, and the last few mm of the rubber tube not covered. It looks as if the fuel pipe has been wrapped with electrical tape and wiring harness wrap. Maybe the leaking fuel has dissolved the plastic tape.

Fuel leaks are obviously dangerous and could ignite at any time (exhaust heat, stray ignition spark etc). Have the hose replaced.

Comment: I see the leak only when I start the engine.